# VBA userform crashes when listbox frmMatchEntryComplete is set

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm hoping somebody can be of help here. I'm having a wacky problem. I have an Excel program with thousands of lines, so I'm not posting code. I'm just hoping someone has experienced such a problem, or something similar.

I have a VBA Userform that has a listbox on it. When I load it the first time, all goes well. When I load it a second time (after unloading it), it crashes and I get the error

> Automation Error
>
> Object invoked has disconnected from it's clients.

I, by chance, discovered that if I change the `MatchEntry` property of the listbox from `frmMatchEntryComplete` to `frmMatchEntryFirstLetter`, the problem does not occur. I am at a total loss to explain this.

Any ideas?

Comment: A good way to troubleshoot problems like this is to remove as much code as you can while still triggering the problem. This also makes it easier to ask for help if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Also posting the code here helps.